# How do I kill all tasks run by a bash file in a screen window?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

Perhaps the answer is already out there, but after reading several Questions i didn't manage to do what I need.

**My situation:**
I am using a machine through `ssh`. I created a `screen` window, I called a `bash` file like the following:

```
for var in 1..N
do
java -option $var
done
```

with `N` very high.

**Question:** Is there a way to kill the all the java tasks launched by the`bash` file at once? Or to kill the screen window and everything is running in the screen?

**Note**: The `java` tasks are running -inside the `screen`- in the foreground. If I try to do `CTRL-C` I can kill only one `java` task at the time.

Comment: Do you have any other processes on that server running with the command 'java -option'? If not, you could do something like "kill $(ps -ef | grep 'java -option' | awk '{print $2}')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find out the process ID of the screen session.
2. Use this pid number to kill screen and all its child processes

For example:

Put `screen` in the background (`Ctrl-Alt + D`)

List your open screen sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

You'll get something like:

```
There is a screen on:
    2222.pts-3.yourmachine    (Detached)
```

The first number is the process ID of the screen session.

Use this number to kill the screen and all its childs:

```
PID=2222
kill $PID
```

If your java application catches some signals, use a less graceful way to kill them, e.g. `kill -9 $PID`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid to kill any running java processes you can do the always usefull "killall -9 java" :)